# jQuery - making text bold with loop and delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I'm trying to create someting like that in jQuery:

```js
var x = 0;

function start(){
    setInterval(function () {return changeText(x++);}, 2000);
}

function changeText(index){
    var words = getTextFromDiv().split("/");
    var result = "";

    for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        if(i == index)
            words[i] = "<b>" + words[i] + "</b>";

        result += words[i];

        if(i != words.length - 1)
            result += "/";
    }
    document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML = result;
    if(x == words.length){
        x = 0;
    }
}

//get text from element without HTML
function getTextFromDiv() {
    var element = document.getElementById('divId');
    return element.innerText || element.textContent;
}

start();
```

```html
<div id="divId">
   aaa / bbb / ccc / eee
</div>
```

I tried to use each loop and delay. But it isn't working. Do you have any idea how to make it?

Comment: What is `x++` doing?

Comment: You should share your HTML (and CSS, if applicable) as well.

Comment: Oh. I forgot. Edited.

Comment: seems like your snippet is working fine, can you explain your problem further? "But it isn't working" does not really help us

Comment: Ok. Forgot. `x++` is returning the old count. But adding 1 on top for next run. `++x` is immediately returning the higher count.